# Simple http request to log in Apache server log

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, apache

I developed a ruby on rails application, I want to log the events on client side to apache log, when i hover on certain divs, i want that to be logged to apache server. Can any one suggest me an idea to send a request to server with out using ajax(since it might cause delay and block if the hover is continous on all the elements), which just sends a request to server, so that it gets logged.

Comment: You want to send a request without AJAX? "_since it might cause delay and block if the hover is continous on all the elements_", what makes you think that? AJAX is asynchronous, by definition, so it's not going to block anything. The request will fire and forget.

Comment: "AJAX" = "Asynchronous JavaScript and XML". It won't block.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a route that will just write a message to the log and then `POST` to that route with jQuery:

```
# config/routes.rb
post '/logs', to: 'logs#create'

# app/controllers/logs_controller.rb
class LogsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    logger.info "Client sent: #{params[:log_message]}"
  end
end

# View
<div class="logging">Test</div>

# JS (using CoffeeScript and jQuery)
$ ->
  $('.logging').on 'mouseenter', (e) ->
    $.post('/logs', {log_message: 'mouse entered'})

  $('.logging').on 'mouseleave', (e) ->
    $.post('/logs', {log_message: 'mouse left'})
```

Comment: Thanks friend... You mean to say an ajax request with out the callbacks..  the response of the request is ignored by the browser.. am i correct?? can you share you knowledge if im wrong and guide me right way frnd

Comment: Correct. But Even if you would add a callback for the response, it would not be blocking because of the way javascript callbacks work.

Comment: I think javascript is single threaded.. so if i make n ajax requests, the execution of callbacks for every response happens one after the other(since single threaded). so the requests waiting to run the callbacks gets pooled. so there is possibility of hanging of browser.. This is my analysis.. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong

Comment: If Im wrong... what exactly is the concept of single threaded in Javascript..??  thanks in advance boss

Comment: Is it a problem if i dont have a call back for response?

Comment: Dont worry about performance so much in advance! AFAIK Requests run pseudo-parallel. Javascript is extremely optimized on modern browsers. Just try it out and you will see if it works, but i am pretty sure you will have no problems.

Comment: No problem if you dont have a callback.